# 404 when reloading a Vue website published to Github pages

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, github-pages

I have deployed the contents of my `/dist` folder in the master branch of `christopherkade.github.io`, which has deployed my [website](https://christopherkade.com/) succesfully.

But when I navigate using the navbar (`christopherkade.com/posts` or `christopherkade.com/work`) and reload the page I get an error by Github pages:

> 404 File not found

Note that my routing is done using Vue router like so:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [    
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/work',
      name: 'Work',
      component: Work
    },
    {
      path: '/posts',
      name: 'Posts',
      component: Posts
    },
    { path: '*', component: Home }
  ]
})
```

And my project is built like such:

```
build: {
    // Template for index.html
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../docs/index.html'),

    // Paths
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../docs'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',

    /**
     * Source Maps
     */

    productionSourceMap: true,
    // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#production
    devtool: '#source-map',

    // Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
    // Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
    // Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
    // npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
    productionGzip: false,
    productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],

    // Run the build command with an extra argument to
    // View the bundle analyzer report after build finishes:
    // `npm run build --report`
    // Set to `true` or `false` to always turn it on or off
    bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
  }
```

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> But when I navigate using the navbar (christopherkade.com/posts or
>   christopherkade.com/work) and reload the page **404 File not found**

**Let me explain why `404 File not found` is being shown**

When `christopherkade.com/posts` is triggered from web browser, the machine to which the domain `christopherkade.com` is mapped is contacted.

The path `/posts` is searched in its server. in your case, i believe the route for `/posts` doesn't exist in the server. As the result `404 is displayed`

**There are few ways to fix this**

To prevent the browser from contacting the server when triggering the request `christopherkade.com/posts`, you can keep `mode : 'hash'` in your route configuration

**How `mode : 'hash'` works?**  **This is one way to fix your issue**

`mode : 'hash'` makes use of default browser behavior which is to prevent http request from triggering the details that exists after `#`

As the result, when you trigger `christopherkade.com/#/posts` , `christopherkade.com` is being triggered by the browser and once response is received the `/posts` route from the `route config` is invoked.

> Lets assume that you have control over the server and you are adamant
>   that you need `#` to be removed from the URL

Then what you could do is to configure server in such a way that server responds with the same page everytime any paths is being sent. Once response is received in the browser, route will automatically kicked off.

*Even in your current program, the routeConfig gets kicked off when you click any links (like work,posts) in your page. This is because the browser behavior is not being invoked at this point.*

[image]

**In your case, you use github for hosting this app with `mode: 'history'`**  i myself have to look for a specific solution to workaround this. i will update my answer once i get it.

i hope this was useful.

Comment: have you been able to get a workaround. Just got that error and wanted to know if there is another way other than using Nuxt js

Comment: @amaugosomto using `hash` seems to be the only solution

Comment: this explaination is good and quite complete.But why do we not have this behaviour when working on local ? Refreshing a page on local server does not show a 404 error, even with mode history, I don't understand the difference with deployment.

Comment: @BenoitPoux this is how browsers handle web requests that are initiated by the webpage. this issue will arise while working with hosting providers like github pages,s3 ..etc and also if you host your static pages behind a reverseProxy like nginx. The way localserver works doesnot reflect the actual working of a production grade server.

Comment: This is meanwhile not the best approach regarding SEO. I do recommend simply not hosting your code on Github pages but rather use Netlify/Vercel or alike.

Comment: @kissu if SPA were are hosted in netlify / vercel, those SPA apps will be SEO friendly?

Comment: @divine an SPA by itself is not that good regarding SEO. But having the navigation as hash is even worse. The best would of course be a history mode for the router + some static/server side thanks to Nuxt. My point was mainly to say that Github Pages is quite cumbersome overall as a setup without much added value when compared to the other platforms. Staring your navigation with a 404 code is not the best start for sure haha.

Answer (score 11):

You can fix this issue by a simple workaround. I combined all the insights from reading multiple issues about this and finally this is what helped me fix this problem.

Solution Logic - You just need a copy of `index.html` with the name `404.html` in the dist folder

**Steps to fix**

Go to you `package.json` file, under scripts add a new script called "deploy" like below, you just need to execute this everytime after you build your page. It will automatically take care of the issue.

```
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
        "deploy": "cd dist && cp index.html 404.html && cd .. && gh-pages -d dist"
    },
```

This will copy the index.html & rename it 404.html and pushes `dist` folder under the branch `gh-pages` and after that your script will appear in the vue ui like below

[image: deploy script appears here]

or

If you are using `git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages` method to push, then edit the `deploy` script in `package.json` to below

`"deploy": "cd dist && cp index.html 404.html`

and then execute the below git command. PS, don't forget to execute this script before manually using `npm script` method or from the `vue ui`

`git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages`

Comment: It turned out to be the simplest method to make the routing work. For my purposes I needed only `cd dist && cp index.html 404.html`.

Comment: Thank you so much Sachin for your insights ! 
I had a similar approach but since I was using Github Actions to deploy my app, I added a step after the build command and it did the trick.

```- name: Build
     run: |
        npm run build
        cp dist/index.html dist/404.html
        ls dist/```

Answer (score 4):

This actually happens since your browser makes a request to `christopherkade.com/posts` URL which doesn't exist (this route is defined in Vue application running from `index.html`).

If you were running your own server, you would probably configure it to render your `index.html` page for any request URI, so your Vue application would be loaded from any path and handle routing by itself.

Speaking of GitHub pages, you can't just configure them to act the same way I described, but fortunately, there is a workaround which uses custom 404 page:
https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I duplicated the `index.html` and renamed it to `404.html`.

In this way, if the page is reloaded, you still get the correct page however this is served through the `404.html file`.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I have created folders for each route (with a script) and placed the index.html in all of them.

404s still don't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Nuxt, this fixes the problem.

**layaouts/blank.vue**

```
<template>
  <nuxt />
</template>
```

**pages/redirect.vue**

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  layout: 'blank',
  fetch({base, redirect, query}) {
    const param = query.p
    if (param === undefined) {
      return redirect('/')
    }
    const redirectPath = '/' + param.replace(base, '')
    return redirect(redirectPath)
  }
}
</script>
```

**static/404.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    var pathName = window.location.pathname;
    var redirectPath = '/<repository-name>/redirect';
    location.href = redirectPath + '?p=' + encodeURI(pathName);
  </script>
</head>
</html>
```

https://gist.github.com/orimajp/2541a8cde9abf3a925dffd052ced9008

Answer (score 0):

Very simple perfect solution just follow the below instruction

1. Add a _redirects file inside the /public folder like /public/_redirects
2. After that add `/*  /index.html  200` into the _redirects file

I think with this solution your redirect problem will be solved