# vue 3 with github pages

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, github-pages, vuejs3

I made some vue page applications.

version info:
"vue": "^3.0.0",
"vue-router": "^4.0.8",

I can run this project in my desktop (windows), and it works good.

But, in github pages, I just could open index.html page.
any other routing pages don't work.

what makes it doesn't work?

my project path: https://github.com/meansoup/votes

which I done ---

- add vue.config.js
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  ? '/votes/'
  : '/',

Comment: works fine, or not? https://meansoup.github.io/ - I think you could only deploy one project to your github pages - so is `/votes` a route or a whole new project?

Comment: I apply hash routing.
It works fine. reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65501787/vue-router-github-pages-and-custom-domain-not-working-with-routed-links