# Vue router with hash mode doesn't work on Github Pages

Tags: vue.js, router

**Can't navigate a specific page by url**

Hello everyone, I have a little problem, I had a "boilerplate" project with Vue3 + Laravel. And I wanted to use link  so people can navigate  specific page, for example here's a link you can navigate

https://klim2020.github.io/

After that you are able to open portfolio page by clicking on Portfolio link at the right top of the page. As you see you have that

```
/cv/en
```

adress  at the address bar

But if you will try to navigate this link from other source you will get Error

```
Cannot GET /cv/en
```

try to navigate from here https://klim2020.github.io/cv/en

Why is this happening can you tell me please?

Comment: have you added the dist folder on your github repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I do recommend hosting on Netlify or Vercel, those will fix the issue that you do have here.
[GH pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71981732/8816585) are just not worth it. And the other 2 services are more flexible, as free and quite powerful.

The issue here being that if you go to a specific path with a "hard navigation", not a client-side one (via vue-router), you SPA will not be in that specific endpoint. Hence why, you will get a 404 (your initial entry point is available a `/`).

You also need to use the [history mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-mode) rather than the current `#` that you do have in your path.

[image]

Best thing? The part explaining how to solve your current issue with Netlify/Vercel is also explained in [a section below](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#netlify) (mainly providing a `redirects/rewrites` configuration).